# How do I set XeLaTeX as my default engine?

Tags: xetex, texlive, latexmk, vim

I use Neovim with the vimtex plugin and `latexmk` but I want to make it use XeLaTeX by default instead of PDFLaTeX because I have to use `fontspec` quite often for my college papers. I use TeX Live.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please let us know what editor you are using, like `WinEdt`, `TeXworks`, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `$pdf_mode` is responsible for the engine used to generate pdfs. You have to set `$pdf_mode` to 5 if you want to use XeLaTeX. You can do that by adding the following line to your configuration file (i.e. `$HOME/.latexmkrc`):

```
$pdf_mode = 5;
```

Possible values for `$pdf_mode` are:

```
0 = no pdf
1 = pdflatex
2 = pdf from ps 
3 = pdf from dvi 
4 = lualatex
5 = xelatex
```

This is well documented in the manual, which you can access either with `man latexmk` or, with TeX Live,  `texdoc latexmk`.

Answer (score 4):

Without considering your tex editor, in order to compile your tex file with xelatex, add `%!TeX program = xelatex` to the first line of your source code. Because according to [this link](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/03/26/nvim_latex_write_preview/), Vimtex supports two TeX directives: **TeX root** and **TeX program**. Please consider the following example:

```
%!TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
This is an example.
\end{document}
```